# How to send text data with internet from app to my raspberry-pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

How can I send text from my android app to raspberry-pi from anywhere through the internet. I search a lot and find that Python is preinstalled in the pi so how can I make in raspberry-pi python server and how to send HTTP request to python server in pi. help please

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way to make http request is using android volley. Check the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Also, you will need to implement the request on your pi.

Another way to do it, is to implement a webserver on the cloud, make the request from android to webserver with volley(save data to cloud), and implement a socket on your pi, that will listen for updates on your web server and request every new data saved on your webserver.

Comment: Ok thank you, i will check it first and then i let you know

Comment: how can i make webserver in pi and implement it on the cloud.

Comment: i recommend using apache, but you might find different options on google.